# i want to ask permission to read email ( google API) but i get invalid_scope

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

here is some code i use to send a request for a user code to show his emails

if my scope is: "email profile" it works but i need access to the emails of the user

i read that the scope for this is "http://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify" but inserting this won't work

How do i have to write the scope for it to work

```
client_id = 'randomtextcorrectimsure.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    client_secret = "alsocorrect"
    data = [
        ('client_id', client_id),
        ('scope', 'http://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify'), 
    ]

    r = requests.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code', data=data)
    print (r.json())
```

Comment: you might want to try following this https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

Comment: @DaImTo i followed that turtorial before and it works but now i want to get the auth from another device like in this tutorial https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices but i need another scope wich i can't get to work

Comment: Your using python with a device?  good luck with that.